# Make color on div change depending on where u click

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `div` and a `button` inside it. I want the `div` to become, for example, red when you click inside the `div`, but if you click on the `button` that's inside, the `div` should become blue instead.

So just to be clear it is only the `div` that should shift color, depending on if the click event is in the `button` or in the `div`.

My problem is that even when the button is clicked it becomes red because the button is inside the div tag.

This i the code I came up with:

```js
var div_div = document.getElementById("div");
var btn_btn = document.getElementById("btn");

div_div.onclick = function() {
  div_div.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

btn_btn.onclick = function() {
  div_div.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

```html
<div id="div" style=" width:200px; height:200px; border:2px solid #000; ">
    <button id="btn">Button</button>
</div>
```

**The button needs to be inside the div.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for the onclick on the button, make sure you use stopPropagation():

```
btn_btn.onclick = function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    div_div.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

This stops the event from "bubbling up" to parent elements/handlers.

Answer (score 1):

The event is bubbling.To prevent it use `stopPropagation`

```js
var div_div = document.getElementById("div");
var btn_btn = document.getElementById("btn");

div_div.onclick = function() {
  div_div.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

btn_btn.onclick = function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
  div_div.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

```html
<div id="div" style=" width:200px; height:200px; border:2px solid #000; ">
  <button id="btn">Button</button>
</div>
```